# what algorithms does AlchemyAPI use?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, alchemyapi

I'm trying to develop something that extract keywords from a text. I know AlchemyAPI work best for this. Now i wanna know what algorithms AlchemyAPI used so that i can implement code of it on my own. Does anyone has any idea about it. Please share it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what specific algorithms AlchemyAPI uses (I'm guessing it is on the extreme end of proprietary), but the Stanford NLP has a lot of information and code that may be useful:

http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml